# Building dropbox-like functionality with Go Language

Tags: file-io, go

I'm new to the Go language and trying to figure out how to so some OS stuff like monitoring files and interacting with the GUI.

I need a program that monitors a directory for file changes like dropbox does. Open/close/update/create/delete etc. When any of these events take place a webservice needs to be notified and the changes submitted including the new/updated file.

I'm also looking for a way to create widgets in the notification areas of MacOS and windows with Go.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify

Comment: Thanks, do you have tips for interacting with the notification areas of the GUI of the OS?

Comment: @user3899177 That depends on which US you are targeting, but I believe that the GTK bindings provide a portable way.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/andlabs/ui